# Detect when a new event is logged in Windows

Tags: event-handling, wmi, event-log

How would i detect in my application, when a new event is logged in the windows event log. Currently i'm running a timer ever 5 minutes to check for new events but it would be much better if i can detect new events in realtime using WMI or .net

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up a WMI [Temporary Event Consumer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392396%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in your app. Note that to monitor the 
Event Log you will need to request the `SeSecurityPrivilege` in your WMI connection (as it's possible you could receive events from the Security log, which require this permission)

These are some example [WQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) queries:

```
// See all events:
select * from __InstanceCreationEvent where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NTLogEvent'

// Catch only specific events: 4202 is a network transport failure
select * from __InstanceCreationEvent where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NTLogEvent'
     and TargetInstance.EventCode=4202

// Catch only events from a specific source: in this case WMI itself.
select * from __InstanceCreationEvent where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NTLogEvent'
     and TargetInstance.SourceName='WinMgmt'
```

Comment: @stuartd : Can you help me (here)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897897/c-monitor-process-creation-and-termination-in-windows]