# Read and display data from variant VT_UNKNOWN

Tags: c++, com, wmi, variant, wmi-query

I wanted to retrieve infromation about every process the moment it opens. Instead of just writing a "dumb" loop that just iterates over all the open processes and checks when something changes, I wanted to do something more elegant.
I wanted to query the creation events of processes and retrieve the information about the process from the event like this:
I used WMI to asynchronously query the __InstanceCreationEvent of Win32_Process instances like this:

```
hr = pSvc->ExecNotificationQueryAsync(
            _bstr_t("WQL"),
            _bstr_t("SELECT * "
                "FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 "
                "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'"),
            WBEM_FLAG_SEND_STATUS,
            NULL,
            pStubSink);
```

When `ExecNotificationQueryAsync` retrieves an event, it calls the user's implementation of the `IWbemObjectSink::Indicate` method and passes it the event as a `IWbemClassObject` interface. (it passes a pointer to an array of all these events).
Now here's the problem. I used `IWbemClassObject::Get`in order to get the data from the `TargetInstance` property (which is the Win32_Process instance). However, the `Get` function outputs the result into a `VARIANT`. when checking the `vt` member of the structure, I found out that the member that contains the valid data is `punkVal`. punkVal's type is `IUnknown`.
Basically my problem is as follows:
How do I get the `Win32_Process` instance through `punkVal`? 
this is my implementation of the `Indicate` method:

```
HRESULT EventSink::Indicate(LONG lObjectCount,
IWbemClassObject **apObjArray)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < lObjectCount; i++)
    {
        IWbemClassObject * InstanceCreationEventInterface = apObjArray[i];

        VARIANT v;
        BSTR strClassProp = SysAllocString(L"TargetInstance");
        HRESULT hr;
        hr = InstanceCreationEventInterface->Get(strClassProp, 0, &v, 0, 0);
        SysFreeString(strClassProp);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && (V_VT(&v) == VT_UNKNOWN))
        {
            wcout << (&v)->punkVal << endl; //How do I use punkVal here to get the Win32_Process instance?
        }
        else
        {
            wprintf(L"Error in getting specified object\n");
        }
        VariantClear(&v);
    }

    return WBEM_S_NO_ERROR;
}
```

Since punkVal's type is `IUnknown*`, the only method that can really be used to retrieve the instance is `IUnknown::QueryInterface` however I don't really see any way to use this method to get the Win32_Process instance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: TargetInstance is also a IWbemClassObject, so you can QI for IWbemClassObject on the IUnknown that you have.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897897/c-monitor-process-creation-and-termination-in-windows

Comment: @SimonMourier thank you, this solved my problem. I've been agonizing over this problem for too long :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TargetInstance is also a IWbemClassObject, so you can QI for IWbemClassObject on the IUnknown that you have.

This answer here on SO demonstrates this: [C++: Monitor process creation and termination in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897897/c-monitor-process-creation-and-termination-in-windows)